# Java CellEditor

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a java application, and I use a custom CellEditor class, but now I want to use it only in the cell in column 5 and row 0, and no longer in the entire column 5.

this is part of the code:

```
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setCellEditor(new ComboBoxCellEditor());
```

I've already tried all forms of questions for our friend ChatGPT.

Comment: Override the `getCellEditor(...)` method of the `JTable`. It has row/column parameters so you can return your custom editor for your specific requirement or invoke `super.getCellEditor(...) ` for all other cases.